# python logging count messages in queue

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging, jython

I've found that in my testing (using `unittest`) some logger messages are being printed after `tearDown`, even after `setUp` of the next test.

Obviously there is `handler.flush()`... but I want to set up a test to test formally that the logger's queue is not emptied before whatever object orders `flush`, and is emptied after it.

NB I'm not sure that this is terribly relevant, but my flavour of Python is in fact Jython.

Comment: it probably depends on the logging handler you use, but e.g. `StreamHandler` flushes [on every emit call](https://github.com/jythontools/jython/blob/master/lib-python/2.7/logging/__init__.py#L875). Also, StreamHandler uses `sys.stderr` by default, which I suppose is routed to a Java PrintStream, so the source of what you are observing might actually be somewhere other than the Jython logging module...

Comment: Thanks... very instructive to go to the code! Yes, I obviously need to gain a much better understanding of exactly what my handler is doing.